# Unity 2019 depth-only camera now overwrites everything

Tags: unity, camera, gui

We have a pretty traditional camera stacking set up: UI camera on top of a everything-else camera.

The UI camera is set to only clear depth, and only draws the UI layer.  The everything-else camera is set to clear via skybox and all layers but UI.  Only the everything-else camera contains a post-processing layer component; disabling it does seem to make everything work the way it used to.

The UI camera has a higher depth than the everything-else camera, in case someone suggests otherwise.

In 2018 this exact arrangement worked as intended.  In 2019, the UI camera's view is the only thing visible.

I've found several forum posts on Unity by Unity Technologies about the light-weight pipeline breaking this functionality, but we're not using any of the new pipelines.  We simply upgraded, and I can't find any indication that we are using the new pipelines.  Supposedly everything works normally as long as you don't use the new pipelines, but this is proving false so far.

Since this camera arrangement is very common, I can't imagine I am alone!

Answer (score 2):

Unchecking "Directly to Camera Target" on the Post Processing Layer component did the trick.  I am not completely certain what the option does yet, but I am guessing it may mean that the post-processing renders its output after all other camera renders, instead of during that particular camera's depth.

Unchecking "Directly to Camera Target" seems to muck with viewport settings in a weird way.  The viewport minimum X value seems to act double-ish when this option is disabled...?  We had a value of 0.24, but now 0.1 is necessary to recreate that.  Very strange.

If anyone can help me understand what's going on, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Here is the tooltip for the Directly to Camera Target setting. It say's it breaks image effects: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nbn61.png